# a friend sent me some weird scrabbles on paper which apparently is a puzzle

Tags: riddle

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
[image: picture3]
[image: picture4]
[image: picture5]
[image: picture6]
These are the papers with the weird scrabbles, now, he says if I manage to solve the puzzle he'll give me 10 euros.

He just gave me a hint, he said it was in English. He also sent me a phrase, I don't know how much it means, though, the sentence was:

> I burnt the roof of my mouth from my pizza

Has anyone got some ideas?

Comment: I hope your friend doesn't mind that you're asking us to help you win the bet... maybe he'll want to pay *us* the 10 euros :P

Comment: I don't see any actual puzzle here. The scribbles say FC and IFC for front cover and inside front cover, then 1-8 for page numbers, then IBC and BC for inside back cover and back cover. Maybe there's some sort of puzzle in how the paper's folded, or something hidden inside, or something like that, but it doesn't look as if the "weird scrabbles" have anything interesting in them.

Comment: @Gareth It's missing 4 and 5. And I think we're meant to solve what the letters stand for.

Comment: I assumed pages 4 and 5 just weren't shown. And figuring out what the letters stand for doesn't seem like much of a *puzzle*.

Comment: Actually, it looks rather as if there are *more* pages not shown where 4,5 would go.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible answers, both of which feel shaky to me.

Based on:

> I burnt the roof of my mouth from my pizza

I'm going to guess that the missing 4 & 5 indicate:

> He didn't blow on his pizza to cool it.
>
>  **Four** and **five** are two numbers between 1 and 10 which are enunciated with a blowing action, which is reminiscent of the act of blowing (*"phoo"*).

---

The other answer I can think of is:

> Your friend's mouth hasn't healed enough to allow him to eat, but he's now hungry.
>  By giving you the pages 1 to 8, that sounds like "**Want to eat**".

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe it is a way of saying that you need to avoid the middle. For a book made out of three folded up pieces of paper, pages four and five would be the two middle pages; he is avoiding those two pages. If you burn the roof of your mouth with pizza you have to avoid the middle of the roof of your mouth for days.